# jQuery, shrink div width from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

As you can see there is a slide to the left and the with decreases from 100% to 0 at the same time.

I want to get this same effect but from left to right.

I can't get it right!

```
jQuery('#target').animate({ width: '0', left: '-25%' }, 1500, 'swing');
```

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RsBNk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty simple. Align the image to the right and then decrease it by 25% using jQuery like below:

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('#target').animate({ width: '0', right: '-25%' }, 1500, 'swing');
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0; /* Modified this line */
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('http://images.icnetwork.co.uk/upl/uxbridgegazette/jul2012/0/4/marc-mccarroll-image-2-304314157.jpg');
    background-position: right; /* EDIT: This property needs to be set */
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RsBNk/5/)

Comment: Hi Harry, it is sliding to the right fine, but is not 'shrinking' (reduce width from left to right from 100% to 0) at the same time. Please see my example. Thanks

Comment: @IGIT It is shrinking from 100% to 0. Works the same as your example except in the opposite direction for me.

Comment: Harry, if you see my example, there are 2 effects going on at the same time, and in yours there is only one.

Comment: Harry, in my example it is sliding to the left (25%) and shrinking from right to left (100% to 0%) at the same time. I want the same but from left to right. Thanks!

Comment: @IGIT: I think I partially understood the thing. Does this area have only an image? Can I do any further changes to your CSS?

Comment: yes, only one image as a background. Please do make as many changes as needed to the CSS. Thanks for helping!!

Comment: @IGIT: Nice question, pity I have exhausted my vote limit for the day. Both animations work fine when executed separately, but when clubbed together they seem to be looking as though the shrink is not happening. You can see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RsBNk/4/). Not saying there is totally no way. I will try further options.

Comment: Harry, I am stuck exactly where you are at the moment. In your solution, the shrink is 'technically' happening but not from left to right as I need, so both animations look like a slide. Please let me know if you find something. You'll be my hero for the day! :)

Comment: @IGIT: Refer to the updated answer. I have added another setting to the CSS and it seems to work as expected :) I have also added a demo (with an increased duration for the effect to be clear).

Comment: Hi Harry, yes, that's it! was the background-position: right; ??

Comment: @IGIT: Yup mate, seems so simple now :D. By the way, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Harry you are my hero of the day! So simple yet not so obvious! You are a rockstar! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps you

```
$('#target').animate({
    width : '0',
    marginLeft: parseInt($('#target').css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        $('#target').outerWidth() : 0
}, 1500, 'swing');
```

check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RsBNk/1/)

Comment: Hi Anil, this will slide it all to the right but it won't shrink it at the same time as in my example. Thanks

Comment: I think it's not shrinking

Comment: Anil, in your demo it slides to the right, and that's fine. But I also want it to 'shrink' (reduce width from left to right from 100% to 0) at the same time. Please see my example. Thanks